# how to know requestlocationupdates method in location manager is working or not in android emulator by using giving min. time

Tags: android

here i make one program in this i set the time in requestlocationsupdates method is 61000 miliseconds .so from emulator in DDMS i change the location lati and longi but dnt press send button. now after 61 seconds why not update new inserted lat long in my emulator automatically after 61 seconds.

here is my code...

```
package com.getlocation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class ShowMap extends MapActivity 
{
    TextView tv;

    /*private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;*/
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // create a map view
        //RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        //mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        //mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //mapView.setStreetView(true);
        //mapController = mapView.getController();
        //mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoon 1 is world view

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 61000,
                10, new GeoUpdateHandler());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
            //mapController.animateTo(point); //    
            //mapController.setCenter(point);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
            tv.append("\n"+String.valueOf(lng));
            Log.d("Tag", "Starting update");

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot..but dear i put one log tag in onlocationChanged method so it should be print in log cat after 61 seconds...but why this is nt happen???? when requestLocationupdates called after 61 seconds so in listener class onLocationChanged method call so there should be print log tag must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@saurabh 
Emulator can not detect location automatically but it detect location if we provide latitude and longitude and press on send button

You are provide initial latitude and longitude in requestLocationUpdate and also setting minimum time and distance so it will work but it can not understand new location without providing latitude and longitude and press send button

so best testing is on device

best of luck